# Custum routing while form submit with get mehod- Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, routes

I am submitting values using zend_from using get method.

I want to do custom routing here.

Here it shows url :

> http://www.example.com/news/index?keyword=world&news_category=&dt_from=&dt_to=&search=Search&limit=10

but I want to show :

> http://www.example.com/news/index/keyword/world/news_category/architecture/dt_from/null/dt_to/null/search/Search/limit/10

IS it possible ?

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: @Martijn Dwars : Thanks. had tried to search first. But I was doing with different perameters. Let my try with it. Will revert.

Comment: The common way to do this is to simply redirect after the form submission. But I'm not sure if it's worth the hassle (or delay to the user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the route set up to process the second url correctly, you can use some javascript to catch the form submit and change it to a redirect with the params placed correctly.